# Encountering CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error after pytorch installaion

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to install pytorch on a remote machine with this config:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.102.04   Driver Version: 450.102.04   CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro RTX 6000     Off  | 00000000:3B:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 33%   27C    P8     6W / 260W |      6MiB / 24220MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Quadro RTX 6000     Off  | 00000000:5E:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 33%   24C    P8     4W / 260W |      6MiB / 24220MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Quadro RTX 6000     Off  | 00000000:86:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 33%   24C    P8     5W / 260W |      6MiB / 24220MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Quadro RTX 6000     Off  | 00000000:AF:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 33%   32C    P8    25W / 260W |    183MiB / 24219MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A    275459      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A    275459      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A    275459      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A    275459      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                173MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A    275608      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                7MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and this is the output of /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --version

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_22_19:09:09_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.221
Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28845127_0
```

I installed pytorch via this command on a fresh conda environment with python 3.9.5

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

yet when I call torch.cuda.is_available(), I encounter this warning and it returns False

```
UserWarning: CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES after program start. Setting the available devices to be zero. (Triggered internally at  /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1623448238472/work/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:115.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
False
```

Comment: How do you start your python environment, have you tried `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python`?